# Abusing sshfs to mount "many" remote folders

Tags: sshfs

Assuming that I build a management interface which lets me easily mount folders from remote machines on a workstation, is there a problem with having, let's say, a half a dozen of sshfs mounts with each remote machine, and this with let's say 4 machines? That would be like 2 dozens of sshfs mounts on the workstation.

Is there an error to this approach? Do other solutions exist? I want to mount selectively because some folders contain a lot of files, and I want those to be excluded from a mount (so I'm mounting around them). The main cause for this is because software like SublimeText tends to start crawling the mounts which is a horrible experience when they are mounted over the network.

Comment: It's 2020, and still can't find an answer to this online. If @Daniel you've tried this, let us know if it worked well or poorly please.

Comment: @junvar I have not tried it. I found sshfs generally not suitable for my use case, since I rely a lot on inotify.